# How exactly does the Thor vs Hulk fight end in Thor: Ragnarok?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, the-incredible-hulk, thor-ragnarok

I couldn't make out what happens at the end of the much anticipated Thor-vs-Hulk fight in Thor: Ragnarok. We see that for most of the fight:

> Thor and Hulk are evenly matched. Hulk starts out strong at the beginning, but Thor finds his powers of thunder / lightning and is able to hold his own.

And at the end of the fight:

> Hulk makes a huge jump, seemingly to finish off Thor. The entire crowd, and the rest of the gladiators, actually seem to sympathize with Thor at this point, but wait for the inevitable and for Hulk to finish off Thor.

Then, suddenly:

> Thor puts up his hand. The scene cuts out to black. We see Thor waking up in a room, which we find later is Hulk's quarters.

So what exactly happens there? One more thing:

> The grandmaster promised Thor his freedom if he defeats his "champion" (Hulk). Since Thor is still on Skaar after the fight, I'm assuming he didn't defeat Hulk.

But there's a contradiction:

> It's implied that all of the Hulk's previous opponents perished during their fight with Hulk. So Thor didn't technically lose either, since he's very much alive after the fight.

Comment: Fighting to death was never a rule.

Comment: Or they just lied to him about being freed.

Comment: I assume that Hulk just kept beating on Thor until he got tired of it, which is pretty much what happened in "Hulk vs. Thor".

Comment: Thor yelled out "Martha!" for no reason and they became best buddies.

Comment: Presumably none of Hulk's previous opponents were a god whom are only capable of being wounded by other gods.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to this quote from Taika Waititi:

> Director Taika Waititi explained the scene to HuffPost, saying, “The last shot is Hulk coming down on Thor after he’s been electrocuted, and then it cuts to another scene.” He continued, “I like to think that the Hulk — even though we didn’t shoot this — I like to think that the Hulk told Grandmaster or the guards that he wanted to keep Thor as a pet.”

[via huffpost](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/heres-who-won-the-fight-between-hulk-and-thor-in-thor-ragnarok_us_5a006ac2e4b0c9653000f6ad)

So I guess

> he was knocked out.  Which meshes with Thor being bewildered and unaware of his surroundings when he woke up in the Hulk's bedroom.

Answer (score 2):

I’m inclined to believe the Hulk was just sparring (playing) with Thor. Reason I say that is because he didn’t finish him, but instead had him transported to his quarters where Thor wakes up. Hulk clearly wants to continue playing (sparring) but Thor has his mind set on leaving.

That fight never featured Hulk getting angrier or stronger, instead it was just a sparring match. I think it has no barring on who is the stronger of the two (which I still believe to be the Hulk) But after Infinity War, who knows... it’s anyone’s guess.

Comment: MCU doesn't get stronger with anger, this has never been established.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that the Hulk would have won. If you look at the fight, Thor hit him with everything he had, and the Hulk still managed to get right up. If it had dragged out for longer, Hulk would just gotten angrier and angrier which would fuel his rage even more, thus giving him more power.

Also it's important to remember that while Thor would definitely be a better fighter, he still could not take on a Savage, yet alone World-Breaker Hulk. He wouldn't get past a traditional angry Hulk, yet alone Savage Hulk. Thor would definitely land some very solid blows, but nothing that could actually kill Hulk. In *The Dark World*, the lieutenant of the Dark Elves was about to kill Thor and he himself was not on par with the Hulk.

Comment: "it's important to remember that while Thor would definitely be a better fighter, he still could not take on a Savage, yet alone World-Breaker Hulk. He wouldn't get past a traditional angry Hulk, yet alone Savage Hulk." What's your source for these claims? It's also worth noting that it's never been established whether the MCU Hulk actually *does* get stronger the angrier he gets.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, the Grandmaster interceded when Thor had the upper hand, electrocuting Thor. I'm guessing that the Grandmaster sensed the presence of the Odin-Force in Thor and did not want to lose his Champion.

Comment: Corroboration for this?

Comment: It's not the Odin force it's just simply his own power. If it we're the Odin force then Thor doesn't have much trouble fighting Hela. :)

Answer (score -4):

Thor won, hands down. This was very visible.

It has to be clarified that for the entire duration of the MCU, Hulk has always been at full strength while Thor barely even tapped a majority of his powers.

During the match, Hulk was going all-out with full rage and strength while Thor (without Mjolnir and not utilizing the full extent of his capabilities) was just initially trying to pacify him and *even then*, Hulk was visibly struggling. With no Mjolnir and no full powers, relying on his strength and agility alone, Thor had a slight upper hand over an enraged Hulk. But then he thought "I'm a god" and accessed his untapped lightning powers.

Hulk was simply overwhelmed. Given the chance, Thor could've killed Hulk if not for the Grandmaster interceding.

So to summarize, Thor technically won. The only way Hulk managed to knock him off was because the Grandmaster cheated.

Comment: Cool story bro, but not an answer to the question that was asked.